# Массив заменить на vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
Cell** m_cells;

Game::Game(bool init)
    :m_cells(new Cell*[BOARD_SIZE])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
        m_cells[row].resize(BOARD_SIZE);
    if (init)
        initializeBoard();
    m_turn = Player::NEUTRAL;
}
```

первую часть я заменил на `vector<vector<Cell>> m_cells;`
А вторую часть я не знаю как правильно надо заменить `Game::Game(bool init) :m_cells(new Cell*[BOARD_SIZE])`

Comment: `m_cells.resize(BOARD_SIZE); for (auto& line : m_cells) line.resize(BOARD_SIZE);` если нигде не промазал, то это и  будет собственно вся "инициализация. Правда нужно будет чуточку убрать new

Comment: Делайте один вектор размером сразу `BOARD_SIZE x BOARD_SIZE`.

Comment: `Game::Game(bool init) : m_cells(BOARD_SIZE, vector<Cell>(BOARD_SIZE)) {if (init) initializeBoard(); m_turn = Player::NEUTRAL;}`